# Number of columns for a specific row using python and csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I want to get the exact number of colums for a given row of a csv file. That means row x and x+1 could have different columns. Using this code:

```
def num_columns(dir,y):
        f=dir+'\\data.csv'
        f=open(f, 'r')
        reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=';')
        n=0
        for row in reader:
            if y==n:
                print(len(row))
                return len(row)
            n+=1
```

where y is the row and dir where the csv is located.

The problem is that it returns the higher value of columns from the document. Not the specific row. That I don't understand, because I'm using "n" precisely to return once its on the row. 
Thanks

Comment: You probably want `n += 1`, regardless of your problem here. Or even better `for n, row in enumerate(reader):`. Otherwise it works only for `y = 0`.

Comment: ups.... you are right. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

First read in your csv using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

Once the data is in a pandas dataframe the function below will return a series with the number of values in each row.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis=1)
```